# Save data in DPS for synchronisation

Tags: adobe-dps

I want to build an app with DPS which will embed a HTML/JS module.
This module will display a form with several questions. After the user completes it, I would like to :

1- Send his choices to a database (with some ajax I guess)
**OR**
2- Store data in the app for further synchronisation

I did not find how to save data offline (like some kind of database), does someone have any idea ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally found [this post](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1087385?tstart=0) from turutosiya. It pretty much answered my questions, time to develop it now.